# Datepicker ui with formtastic, rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-datepicker, formtastic

I use rails 3.1, formtastic 2.0.2 and datepicker ui

I made datepicker_input.rb:

```
 class DatepickerInput < Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput
include Formtastic::Inputs::Base

    def input_html_options
        super.merge(:class => "datepicker")
    end 
 end
```

In application.js I wrote:

```
 $('input.datepicker').datepicker()
```

I use it in my form like :as => :datepicker. I see calendar, pick date and everything is fine except for it doesn't fill column in my model. The only thing that I noticed is that when I fill first date and then all the other fields - it works. When date field is the last - it doesn't work. There is no errors, params[:model_name][:date_field] is not empty just nil in place of date that I chose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error was in date format - database just couldn't take format that returned datepicker.